# For the purpose of magic immunity, does Counterspell target the caster or the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, immunities, counterspelling

In the MM it states that the rakshasa is immune to magic of 6th level or lower. Does this include the counterspell spell or does counterspell target the spell and not the creature?

Answer (score 31):

*Counterspell* says that:

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell. If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell fails and has no effect. If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a success, the creature's spell fails and has no effect.

We can contrast this to *Dispel Magic*, which specifically allows you to target

> one creature, object, or magical effect within range.

While *Counterspell* doesn't explicitly state that you are casting it on the creature rather than the spell itself, phrasing like "a creature in the process of casting a spell" rather than "a spell being cast" and "If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower" rather than "if the spell being cast is 3rd level or lower" suggests to me that *Counterspell* does indeed target the creature rather than the spell itself.

That being the case, the rakshasa would be immune to *Counterspell* unless it was cast out of a 7th level or higher spell slot.

Comment: Regardless of one's personal interpretation of the wording, the fact is that no target is explicitly defined. So, logically, you can't say with any certainty one way or the other. It's as open to interpretation as the wording.

Comment: This question is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=16): "**Does *counterspell* target the caster or the spell you’re trying to counter?** *Counterspell* targets the other spellcaster." You may want to update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

I would like to offer a different point of view from [the one presented by Miniman](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67599/for-the-purpose-of-magic-immunity-does-counterspell-target-the-caster-or-the-sp/67601#67601) and backed by the official Sage Advice Compendium (link in the comments):

The spell [*Counterspell*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) does not specify a target but both its name and effect seem to refer to a spell rather than a caster. As such, it is the spell that suffers the effects of *Counterspell*, namely the failure to being cast. As a consequence, the caster is not able to successfully complete the casting of the spell but they themselves are unaffected. As such, while the [Rakshasa](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/rakshasa) is immune to magic of 6th level or lower, the magic he produces is not.

Therefore, I would argue that a spell cast by a Rakshasa can be counterspelled much in the same way that an illusion cast by a Rakshasa could be dispelled.

Comment: This question is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=16): "**Does *counterspell* target the caster or the spell you’re trying to counter?** *Counterspell* targets the other spellcaster." You may want to update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer. But I would like to keep it here as I think some players might find the point of view interesting.

Comment: I edited your answer to use the correct name for the Sage Advice Compendium. However, you state your answer is backed by the Compendium, but your answer (it targets the spell) *contradicts* the official Sage Advice one (it targets the caster). A further edit is needed to clarify this.

Comment: Miniman's view is backed by the compendium, not mine.

Answer (score 11):

Based on [an unofficial response from Jeremy Crawford on Twitter (regarding whether Counterspell affects spells from magical items)](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/792412232432758784), I would say that it is the creature that is targeted and not the spell.  His words were:

> Counterspell targets a creature casting a spell, no matter the source of the spell (the creature, an item, etc.).

Comment: This question is now explicitly addressed in the latest [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=16): "**Does *counterspell* target the caster or the spell you’re trying to counter?** *Counterspell* targets the other spellcaster." You may want to update your answer accordingly.